# retrieve fields from logs based on a condition from AWS cloudwatch log insight query

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am storing a message in a log stream of aws. For a particular time interval these are the 2 logs on which I need to write a query which I will run on log insight.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abdjZ.png)

I want to write a query which will return the differnce of time stamps(in minutes) between (finished at field from pipeline_2)  &  (started at field from pipeline_1)

Note: time stamps are in this format (2023-04-14T19:10:47.494-05:00), in order to make the logs compat I removed micro seconds and the timezone

I have tried to calculate both these values individually by running 2 different scripts but unable to achieve that, I see a very limited options with aws log insight and also I am not an expert at it, please help